# Rejected article submitted to other journal?

Tags: publications, peer-review, rejection

Once an article submitted for publication is rejected can I send it to another journal? If so, what are good criteria and tips for doing that?

Comment: Not only can you, but I've had a journal's rejection notification include an offer for publishing in another (non-predatory) journal, pending modifications requested by the referee.  The offer came from someone other than the editor communicating the rejection to me.  I didn't inquire exactly how this happened. I think the editors decided to review it for a final decision, and one of those was an editor on another journal he felt it would be appropriate for, and got permission to make the offer this way after the original journal decided not to publish it.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy This is sometimes a standard practice within a "family" of related journals, often passing from a more prestigious and general journal to a less prestigious but more community-specific journal.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one you've been rejected, you can submit elsewhere.

The best way to proceed is to take the feedback you got in the rejection letter seriously, which will usually lead to one of two actions:

- If you got an editorial rejection without review due to problems in scope or significance, then pick a better suited journal (usually more narrowly focused on your area).
- If you got a rejection with review, then improve the article to address the objections of the reviewers.

Good luck, and know that even good research can sometimes spend years in the cycle before it finally is sufficiently well improved and targeted that it can find a good home.

Comment: The alternative is basically to just send the paper out unchanged to another lower tier journal in hopes that it will get through review their.  The problem with this strategy is that you often end up with the same reviewer, and they really hate it when they get asked to review an unchanged manuscript...

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you, jakebeal and Brian Borchers!

Comment: @BrianBorchers Absolutely, which is why I didn't even suggest it as a respectable strategy.